# What happens when accessing 0x00ABBA?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, virtual-memory, memory-access

Given the following page table with a 24 Bit virtual address and 4KB page size and 4 byte long entries (%X means hexadecimal values):

[image]

I don't understand how to translate e.g. address %X00ABBA here. I really tried but I don't understand. I know I have 12 bits for the VPN, so I take 00A and look it up in the page table. But how do I look it up here? V = Valid Bit, M = Modify Bit, COW = Copy-on-Write Bit, PFN = Page Frame Number

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Each time you access this address, a queen starts dancing somewhere.

Comment: Hint: lookups can _fail_.